# Managing problems since the 80s

Tags: riddle, visual, rebus

> **What is this:**
>   Whenever things go awry, you'll have to look-out for him/her/it, and he/she/it may help you.

[image]

**HINT:**

> The first picture shows Dhanush, the singer of the viral youtube video song  "Kolaveri Di". Dig deeper and you'll find the answer.

Comment: Why this + fries + Hitler + keys = Ytisfrysitlerkeace

Comment: So is this basically a 4 Pics 1 word puzzle (like the mobile game, in which all the pictures relate to one word)???

Comment: Nope. 4 pics 4 words which finally take you to the final solution.

Comment: @Alexis What's that? Ytisfrysitlerkeace?

Comment: It is gibberish. A joke answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer might be

> Control-Alt-Delete

---

### Explanation

Image 1:

> **THREE** (The song "Kolaveri Di" is from a Tamil psychological thriller film called "3".)

Image 2:

> **FINGER** (potato fingers)

Image 3:

> **SALUTE**

Image 4:

> **KEYS** (piano keys)

Conclusion:

> 1. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-finger_salute, "Three-finger salute" is a jocular term for the three-key command Control-Alt-Delete.
>  2. Whenever things go awry with my PC, I reboot it by Control-Alt-Delete.
>  3. Control-Alt-Delete came up in the 1980s with the MS-DOS operating system.

Comment: Perfect. Correct solution and explanation.

Comment: I found this puzzle quite difficult.  Already yesterday I had the vague idea that this might be related to a computer keyboard ("since the 80s" plus piano "keys"), but only today I was able to make the right connections.

Comment: Interesting.  I've never even heard of the phrase "potato fingers", before.  Never would have guessed it.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha me either! but I get it now.

Comment: Funny, I would have thought that "potato fingers" was a term that would apply to someone that requires a "dialing wand".

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer here as I can't figure out any more of it.

First image might refer to... **CONFIRMED**

> **Three**, from 3, the movie that "Why This Kolaveri Di" features in.

Second image could be...

> Fries, McDonalds, M, french fries

Third may be...

> Hitler, heil, leader, Third Reich, Fuhrer

Fourth may be...

> Piano, keys, ivory, keyboard

Comment: You are on the right track.. The first word for the four letter clue is 'Three'.

Comment: Perhaps this got something to do with: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=three+fries+short+of+a+happy+meal

Comment: The third may also refer to Nazi or salute.

Comment: atleast two of the three remaining clues are already there in all the guesses combined, between @feelinferrety and the comments